# How to debug an unspecified error ($80004005) during DirectShow put_Enable call on Capture filter?

Tags: delphi, filter, directshow, hresult, dspack

I have a DirectShow application written in Delphi 6 using the DSPACK component library.  I am having a strange problem enabling an input line on a Filter.  I search the pins until I find the input line, in this case named 'Microphone', and call put_Enable(true) on it while the Filter Graph is active.  When I do this I get an $80004005 "unspecified error" as the HRESULT.

I am setting the output audio media type for the Filter before enabling the input line, yet something is not working right.  The original DirectShow sample I worked off of to create my application works fine.  I believe I am following the exact same steps building my Filter Graph, and it is possible I missed something of course.  Does anyone have any tips or ideas for things I can try to fix this problem?  the code snippet below shows partially what I am doing, but not all the steps leading up to it since they are extremely lengthy.  The capture device I am using for testing is a VOIP headset with a single input line named 'Microphone'.

```
// The function I call to find an enable the first input line I find in the filter.
function findAndEnableFirstInputLineFound(intfBaseFilter: IBaseFilter; out strInputLineUsed: string): boolean;
var
    thePinList: TPinList;
    i: integer;
    ABool: LongBool;
begin
    strInputLineUsed := '';

    if not Assigned(intfBaseFilter) then
        raise Exception.Create('(findAndEnableFirstInputLineFound) The base filter interface object is unassigned.');

    // Now enable the first input source we can find.
    Result := false;
    thePinList := TPinList.Create(intfBaseFilter);

    try
        if thePinList.Count > 0 then
        begin
            // Scan the pin list looking for an input pin.
            i := 0;

            while (i < thePinList.Count) and (not Result) do
            begin
                if thePinList.PinInfo[i].dir = PINDIR_INPUT then
                begin
                    // Found one.  Enable it.
                    with thePinList.Items[i] as IAMAudioInputMixer do
                    begin
                        CheckDSEror(put_Enable(true)); // $80004005 error occurs here.

                        // Return the name of the input line used.
                        strInputLineUsed := thePinList.PinInfo[i].achName;
                    end; // with thePinList.Items[i] as IAMAudioInputMixer do

                    Result := true;
                    break; // Stop looping.
                end; // if thePinList.PinInfo[i].dir = PINDIR_INPUT then

                Inc(i);
            end; // while()
        end; // if thePinList.Count > 0 then
    finally
        thePinList.Free;
    end; // try
end;


// The initialization procedure that calls the function above.  It is run after the
//  the Filter Graph is activated but before it is played.
procedure TDXChain_wavaudio.initializeCaptureFilter;
var
    theMediaType: TMediaType;
    intfCapturePin: IPin;
    aryEnabledInputLines: TDynamicStringArray;
begin
    theMediaType := nil;
    intfCapturePin := nil;
    aryEnabledInputLines := nil;

    if not FFilterGraph.Active then
        raise Exception.Create('(TDXChain_wavaudio.Create::initializeCaptureFilter) The Filter Graph is INACTIVE.');

    if Assigned(FCaptureFilter) then
    begin

        // Make sure the Capture Filter's output pins supports the
        //   configured WAV format.
        with FOwner.ati_WaveFormatEx do
        begin
            // if not Assigned(findAudioMediaTypeByFormat(FCaptureFilter_mediatypes, nSamplesPerSec, wBitsPerSample, nChannels)) then
            theMediaType := findAudioMediaTypeExt_outputs(FCaptureFilter as IBaseFilter, nSamplesPerSec, wBitsPerSample, nChannels);

            if not Assigned(theMediaType) then
                // The capture device does not directly support the desired
                //  WAV format.  This is not allowed currently.
                raise Exception.Create('(TDXChain_wavaudio.Create::initializeCaptureFilter) The audio input device''s output pins does not support the given WAV format: '
                        + CRLF
                        + Format('(Device name: %s, Sample Rate: %d, Bits Per Sample: %d, Number of Channels: %d)',
                                    [FOwner.FCaptureFilterConfigInfo.filterName, nSamplesPerSec, wBitsPerSample, nChannels])
                    );

            // -------------- SET OUTPUT PINS TO MEDIA TYPE -------------

            // Set the output pins to the desired format.
            setPinAudMediaType_outputs(FCaptureFilter, theMediaType.AMMediaType);

            // Don't need the media type anymore.
            FreeAndNil(theMediaType);
        end; // with FOwner.ati_WaveFormatEx do

        // Enable at least one input line.
        if FOwner.FCaptureFilterConfigInfo.inputPinName = '' then
        begin
            //  No input name was specified so use the first one found.
            if not findAndEnableFirstInputLineFound(FCaptureFilter as IBaseFilter, FOwner.FInputLineUsed) then
                raise Exception.Create(
                    '(TDXChain_wavaudio.Create::initializeCaptureFilter) Unable to find a suitable input line for the audio input device named: '
                    + FOwner.FCaptureFilterConfigInfo.filterName);
        end
        else
        begin
            // Now find the desired available input line and enable it.
            if not findAndEnableInputLineByName(FOwner.FCaptureFilterConfigInfo.inputPinName, FCaptureFilter as IBaseFilter, FOwner.FInputLineUsed) then
                raise Exception.Create(
                    '(TDXChain_wavaudio.Create::initializeCaptureFilter) Unable to find the input line named ('
                    + FOwner.FCaptureFilterConfigInfo.inputPinName
                    + ') for the audio input device named: '
                    + FOwner.FCaptureFilterConfigInfo.filterName);
        end; // else - if FOwner.FCaptureFilterConfigInfo.inputPinName = '' then

        aryEnabledInputLines := getEnabledInputLineNames(FCaptureFilter as IBaseFilter);

        if Length(aryEnabledInputLines) < 1 then
            raise Exception.Create('(TDXChain_wavaudio.Create::initializeCaptureFilter) No input lines are enabled..');

        // ------------------ BUFFER LATENCY --------------------

        // Get a reference to the output pin for audio the capture device.
        with FCaptureFilter as IBaseFilter do
            CheckDSError(findPin(StringToOleStr('Capture'), intfCapturePin));

        if not Assigned(intfCapturePin) then
            raise Exception.Create('(TDXChain_wavaudio.Create::initializeCaptureFilter) Unable to find the audio input device''s Capture output pin.');

        // Set the capture device buffer to 50 ms worth of audio data to
        //  reduce latency.  NOTE: This will fail if the device does not
        //  support the latency you desire so make sure you watch out for that.
        setBufferLatency(intfCapturePin as IAMBufferNegotiation, FOwner.ati_BufferLatency_ms, FOwner.FMediaType);
    end; // if Assigned(FCaptureFilter) then
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suppose that `Audio Capture Filter` relies on underlying hardware and driver when trying to enable certain pin for mixing into recording. If the underlying layer fails with an error, you have this error forwarded to you.

As a guess, capture hardware might be indicating an error when you are trying to enable a pin when another pin is already enabled, that is it is actually unable to do mixing of the two.

Comment: That was exactly it.  I confirmed that by going in to Graph Edit and it would not allow more than one connection on a downstream filter's input pin.  Would you happen to know if DirectShow relies on the CheckConnect() call return to determine if a Filter accepts more than one input or output pin connection, or is it some other Filter method that determines this?

Comment: A filter is free to add new pins any time. The same applies to removing unconnected existing pins. Every time an application or filter graph needs to checking filter pins, it uses enumerator to see what pins are available.

Comment: Thanks.  What method(s) should I modify then to tell the Filter Graph that my singular Output pin is already in use and that I am not accepting new Output connections?  In other words, what calls made to the filter facilitate the pin enumeration and what field/property in the pin lets the caller know the pin is unavailable?  Or what flag am I checking during enumeration to decide whether or not a pin should be included in the returned list, if it works that way instead?

Comment: Whebn a pin is connected and indicates connection in its `IPin::ConnectedTo` and `IPin::ConnectionMediaType` methods, it is assumed that it won't accept a new connection until it is disconnected. No additional calls needed.